# Unknown Runtime Error occurs when setting a range

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

This is a subroutine of a larger program (I can copy and paste the whole thing if needed).  I'm getting an unknown runtime error, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I've spent a couple hours getting frustrated, and decided to come to you guys for help!

Quick Edit:  I'm trying to find a specific column header, and then select that entire column (minus the header) as the range.

```
Sub YearSmash(MyString)
    With objSheetSrc
        Set FoundCell = .Range("A1:BZ1").Find(MyString, , , 1)
        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        MsgBox(FoundCell)

        Set rng1 = .Range(FoundCell.Offset(1), FoundCell.Offset(1).End(xlDown))

        MsgBox(rng1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Error is occuring on the following line:

```
Set rng1 = .Range(FoundCell.Offset(1), FoundCell.Offset(1).End(xlDown))
```

Any ideas?  Also, there are no invalid values, errors, or NULL values in the data I am trying to pull.

Thanks,

Andrew

Editted to show code in its entirety:

```
Const xlFilterCopy = 2
strPathSrc = "C:\test" ' Source files folder
strMaskSrc = "*.xlsx" ' Source files filter mask

dtmDate = Date
strMonth = Month(Date)
strDay = Day(Date)
strYear = Right(Year(Date), 2)
strFileName = "C:\test\Results\" & strMonth & "-" & StrDay & "-" & strYear & " Results.xlsx"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objWorkbook.SaveAs(strFileName)
objExcel.Quit

'strPathDst = "C:\test\Results\Results.xlsx" ' Destination file
strPathDst = strFileName

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
Set objWorkBookDst = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPathDst)
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShellApp.NameSpace(strPathSrc)
Set objItems = objFolder.Items()
objItems.Filter 64 + 128, strMaskSrc
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
x = 1
y = 1
MsgBox("Working")
For Each objItem In objItems
    Set objWorkBookSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objItem.Path)
    Set objSheetSrc = objWorkBookSrc.Sheets(1)
    Set objSheetDst = objWorkBookDst.Sheets(1)
    For Each Cell In objSheetSrc.Range("A1:Z15")
        If Cell.MergeCells = True Then
            Set objRange = Cell.EntireRow
            objRange.Delete
        End If
    Next

    'Set FoundCell = objSheetSrc.Range("A1:BZ1").Find("Device", , , 1)

    'For Each Cell In objSheetSrc.Range(FoundCell.Offset(1,0), objSheetSrc.Cells(objSheetSrc.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(-4162)).Cells
        'If Cell.Value <> "*MSP430*" Then
        '   Cell.EntireRow.Delete
        'End If
    'Next

    Set objSheetDst = objWorkBookDst.Sheets(1)

    Call FindCell("Sales Region")
    Call FindCell("Sales Area")
    Call FindCell("TSR Role")
    Call FindCell("My Account")
    Call FindCell("Account Class")
    Call FindCell("Project Name")
    Call FindCell("Device")
    Call FindCell("AUP")
    Call FindCell("Qty Per Board")
    Call FindCell("Device Status")
    Call FindCell("Project Status")
    Call FindCell("Project Kickoff")
    Call FindCell("Market")
    Call FindCell("SBE")
    Call FindCell("SBE-1")
    Call FindCell("SBE-2")
    Call FindCell("2013 Q1")
    Call FindCell("2013 Q2")
    Call FindCell("2013 Q3")
    Call FindCell("2013 Q4")
    Call FindCell("2014 Q1")
    Call FindCell("2014 Q2")
    Call FindCell("2014 Q3")
    Call FindCell("2014 Q4")
    Call FindCell("2015 Q1")
    Call FindCell("2015 Q2")
    Call FindCell("2015 Q3")
    Call FindCell("2015 Q4")
    Call FindCell("2016")
    Call YearSmash("2016 Q1")
    Call FindCell("2016 Q1")
    Call FindCell("2017")
    Call FindCell("2018")

    objWorkBookSrc.Close
Next

objExcel.Visible = True

Sub FindCell(MyString)
    Do While objSheetDst.Cells(x, y).Value <> ""
        y = y + 1
    Loop

    If MyString = "Sales Region" And y > 2 Then
        y = 1
        Do While objSheetDst.Cells(x, y).Value <> ""
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End If

    Set FoundCell = objSheetSrc.Range("A1:BZ1").Find(MyString, , , 1)
    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set objRangeSrc = FoundCell.EntireColumn
    objRangeSrc.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , objSheetDst.Cells(x, y), False
End Sub

Sub YearSmash(MyString)
    With objSheetSrc
        Set FoundCell = .Range("A1:BZ1").Find(MyString, , , 1)
        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Set lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(FoundCell.Row + 1, FoundCell.Column), .Cells(lRow, FoundCell.Column))

        MsgBox rng1.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub YearSmash(MyString)
    Dim objSheetSrc As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim FoundCell As Range, rng1 As Range
    Dim MyString As String

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set objSheetSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With objSheetSrc
        Set FoundCell = .Range("A1:BZ1").Find(MyString, , , 1)

        If FoundCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        '~~> Find the last row in that column
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Construct your range from one cell offset
        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(FoundCell.Row + 1, FoundCell.Column), _
                          .Cells(lRow, FoundCell.Column))

        MsgBox rng1.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS**

I tested it in vbscript and it works perfectly

```
Dim oXLApp, olXLWb, objSheetSrc
Dim MyString, lRow, FoundCell, rng1

Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

oXLApp.Visible = True

'~~> Sample File
Set olXLWb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")

'~~> Change as applicable
Set objSheetSrc = olXLWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

'~~> Sample String
MyString = "Sid"

With objSheetSrc
    Set FoundCell = .Range("A1:BZ1").Find(MyString, , , 1)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Find the last row in that column
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(-4162).Row

        '~~> Construct your range from one cell offset
        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(FoundCell.Row + 1, FoundCell.Column), _
                          .Cells(lRow, FoundCell.Column))

        MsgBox rng1.Address
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Siddharth, I appreciate your quick response.  From looking at your code, that looks like what I'm trying to do... unfortunately, it is still throwing me an Unknown Runtime Error.

Comment: lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
Is giving the error.  Like I said, this subroutine is being called as part of a larger subroutine, if you need me to post the code in its entirety let me know!

Comment: Yes that would help as that line shouldn't give an error as the objects are fully qualified

Comment: Oh you are doing this in VBSCRIPT? If yes then change the line `lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row` to `lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(-4162).Row` as `xlUp` is an Excel Constant.

Comment: That fixed the Unknown Error problem.  Now I'm running into another similar problem that I had before.  The same line is now giving the error "Object Required".  I remembered that earlier, when I was trying to use .Row, or .Column I was receiving these errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have sandwiched that code between `With objSheetSrc - End With` Block? Else you will have to use it like this `lRow = objSheetSrc.Cells(objSheetSrc.Rows.Count, FoundCell.Column).End(-4162).Row`

Comment: I was actually thinking about that, but it's for sure sandwiched between the two With - End With blocks.  I'm now back to a Runtime Error trying to use this code instead to find the last row .... `Set lRow = .Range(FoundCell, .Range(FoundCell.Column & .Rows.Count).End(-4162)).Rows.Count`

Comment: As I said... no more object required, but now a runtime error again.  Just cna't win!

Comment: Ok one moment. Let me test it in vbscript